# how to prevent applying discount for a product

Tags: hooks, commerce

I'm trying to change the product price based on the purchase type. I have added two radio buttons in `add to cart` form, one is retail and another one is wholesale. The default value is retail, so the default action will be executed. When user selects `wholesale` option I need to set the price of`whole sale price` and want to disable the discount for this product.

Here is my code :

```
function mycart_commerce_product_calculate_sell_price_line_item_alter($line_item){
    $pid = menu_get_object();
    $pid=$pid -> field_product['und'][0]['product_id'];
    $product=commerce_product_load($pid);
    $wh_price=$product->field_wholesale_price['und'][0]['amount'];
    $wh_currency=$product->field_wholesale_price['und'][0]['currency_code'];
    $line_item->commerce_unit_price['und']['0']['amount']=$wh_price;
    $line_item->commerce_unit_price['und']['0']['currency_code']=$wh_currency;
}
```

from above code I'm able set the product price to `whole sale price`. But I don't know how to disable `discount` for this particular product.

Can anyone please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can just alter the rule that commerce discounts provides and add a condition by the products you want to exclude. Bear in mind that when you alter the rule that commerce discounts provides, you can't modify the discount from the discount interface anymore.

If you've created a discount through the Commerce Discount interface, you can exclude products using the Negate checkbox.

[image]

Comment: I just want to avoid discount for that particular product is it possible ?.

Comment: Extended my answer

Comment: I think you didn't got my question. The scenario is not for a particular product all time. I have added two radio buttons to `add to cart` form in code. When user selects `wholesale` option I want to avoid discount for that product.

Comment: I found this [link](http://www.zyxware.com/articles/3588/drupal-how-to-create-a-custom-rule-condition-for-ubercart-module) was useful. However do you know what is the `rule type` for `DC`.

Comment: If what you did is to create a line item attribute element, you can always check out how to create inline conditions, and that will enable you to use Commerce Discounts and its rules, example in http://www.agoradesign.at/blog/drupal-commerce-building-commerce-discount-rules-based-node-categories

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used discount rules before. But I did use tax rules. I altered it by this hook also . I think you can do same thing in this hook.

First, use kpr($line_item->commerce_unit_price) to check all the values.
Then change them in this hook.

For my case, the price is:

```
$line_item->commerce_unit_price['und']['0']['amount']=$myPrice;
$line_item->commerce_unit_price['und']['0']['data']['components']['0']['price']['amount']=$myPrice;
```

And the tax is:

```
$line_item->commerce_unit_price['und']['0']['data']['components']['1']['price']['amount']=$myTax;
```

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: there is no discount `discount` set in `line_item` or `$line_item->commerce_unit_price`. I think the only way is to modifying the rule itself.